# Limitation on sending messages to a large number of invalid tokens for gcm push notification?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Now we want to send some notification to users who have not login for a long time. But their push-tokens in our db may be expired.

What will happen if we send push notifications to too many invalid tokens?

Will google allow this without any limit?

Answer (score 1):

GCM Registration IDs don't expire as far as I know. The Registration IDs you are referring to are not invalid (since they are not some random IDs you generated. You got them from the GCM server). In the worst case, you will get a `NotRegistered` error for some of them, which will let you know which Registration IDs you should delete.

You shouldn't have any problems sending messages to those Registration IDs.

Answer (score 0):

When Sending Push notification, it can only be sent with 1000 parameters of token at a time.
Google does not know if the token are expired or not in the first instance.

irrespective of token being expired on not the same number of token is assumed to the sent

All token will hit the server first before being sent to client which their parameter are included